# Correcting a thesis after publication

Tags: thesis, thesis-committee

I defended my PhD thesis over 5 years ago and obtained my PhD, but I was not happy with the thesis (a classic saying of many an academic, I know), but felt pressured to submit and move on to new things. Whilst I still like the thesis idea, what I wrote, the references, and the results, I now know I should have used a totally different mathematical theory to describe the proposed system/algorithm. Would a University allow someone to update a thesis after it has been "published" in the sense it's in the library and departmental library? Is there any point in asking the University or will this just be thrown out?

Comment: If I correctly understand the question, your 5-year-old thesis isn't actually wrong (unlike the situation in the "duplicate" question) but you now have a much better approach to the same topic. I would not expect the university to allow you to change the thesis after this much time. You can write up the new approach as a paper (referring to your thesis). If it's new enough, that paper could be published, but even if it's deemed too similar to your thesis for publication, you could make it available on the internet with an indication that the new version supersedes your thesis (or part of it).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do remember emailing my supervisor around 4-5 years ago to explain this, but he ignored my email. But since my mathematical abilities have improved so much this still niggles at me. From your comment and answers in the duplicate I see one option is to make available online my thesis update, and a hard copy of an "update" manuscript to coincide with the original thesis.

Comment: No. Published is published unless you want to retract the thesis, which is most likely very difficult. This sounds like a case where you should write another paper, where you show the advantages of the other method

Comment: I think im going to go for the accompanying document route, and/or put the updated thesis online.